# Regularity of sigma finite measures on borel sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

The following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uGhn.jpg) can be found in Kallenberg - Foundations of Modern Probability as Lemma 1.16, I do not understand why it is okay to assume $\mu$ is bounded. I am trying to show that given the result holds for all bounded sigma finite measures, it holds for all sigma finite measures, and have been unable to do so. Therefore I would be very grateful for further elucidation on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite on $S$, there exists some sequence of measurable subsets $S_k \uparrow S$ with $\mu(S_k) < \infty$. Each of these measurable subsets itself generates a sigma algebra which we can call $\mathcal{A}_k$, derived from the original Borel sigma algebra on $S$ i.e. $\mathcal{B}(S)$ which we'll just call $\mathcal{A}$ for short henceforth. :

$$\mathcal{A}_k = \{E \cap S_k : E \in \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B}(S)\}$$

You can check that each such $\mathcal{A}_k$ is indeed a sigma algebra on the set $S_k$. Moreover, it can be shown that each $\mathcal{A}_k$ is bounded, because for every $F \in \mathcal{A}_k$ there exists some $F' \in \mathcal{B}(S)$ with $F = F' \cap S_k$. That's just the definition of $\mathcal{A}_k$. And so,

$$\mu(F) = \mu(F' \cap S_k) \leq \mu(S_k) < \infty$$

So, we now have a family of bounded sigma algebras increasing to the original sigma algebra. And we can use continuity of the measure from below to show that when the result holds on all bounded algebras, and thus each bounded algebra in our sequence, then it follows for the limit of that sequence.

I'll just show you how it follows for one of your results, the other is similar. So you want to show:

$$\mu(B) = \sup_{F \subset B} \mu (F)$$

For all $B \in \mathcal{A}$, where $F$ is open. Start by defining $B_k = B \cap S_k$. Since each $B_k \in \mathcal{A}_k$ and $\mathcal{A}_k$ is bounded, we have by assumption that:

$$\mu(B_k) = \sup_{F \subset B_k} \mu(F)$$

Now, since $S_k \uparrow S$, then $B_k \uparrow B$, so by the continuity of our measure from below:

$$\mu(B_k) \uparrow \mu(B)$$

Now, we have both a supremum and a limit in $\mu$. With both, we can get as close as we want to $\mu(B)$, in other words for any $\epsilon$ we can find an open set $F$ and some $k$ with:

$$F \subset B_k \subset B$$

and $\mu(B) - \epsilon < \mu(F) < \mu(B)$ which implies that the supremum limit is indeed $\mu(B)$. Not sure how that only warranted a mere throwaway sentence "We may clearly assume that $\mu$ is bounded" in the image you sent. Maybe there's a more obvious explanation.